# Return details of the latest bill linked to the user

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max

I have two different sources of information and I am trying to marry them together to get information relating to a customer and their last bill. I have managed to get details of each customer and their max billing period end date but I am unsure as to how I can then get the details from the associated bill. I have the following query:

```
SELECT new_mprnnumber, 
       new_customernumber, 
       MAX(b.billingPeriodEndDate) as 'Billed up to date'
FROM [CRM].[crm4_MSCRM].[dbo].[AccountExtensionBase] as a
inner join Billing.dbo.bill as b 
  on a.new_mprnnumber = b.MPRN
where new_accountstage = 7
and new_accounttype = 2  
group by new_mprnnumber, 
         new_customernumber
GO
```

The bill has fields like amount due etc but I only want to return details of those from the max dated bill, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: I am using SQL server

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE with [row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
with CTE as
(
select a.new_mprnnumber, 
       a.new_customernumber,
       b.*, 
       row_number() 
         over (partition by new_customernumber -- add additional partitions as you would group bys
               order by billingPeriodEndDate desc) as r_ord 
from AccountExtensionBase a
inner join bill  b
  on a.new_mprnnumber = b.MPRN
where new_accountstage = 7
and new_accounttype = 2 
)
select *
from CTE
where r_ord = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your query into a CTE and then link back to table bill:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT new_mprnnumber, 
   new_customernumber, 
   MAX(b.billingPeriodEndDate) as MaxBillDate
FROM [CRM].[crm4_MSCRM].[dbo].[AccountExtensionBase] as a
inner join Billing.dbo.bill as b 
  on a.new_mprnnumber = b.MPRN
where new_accountstage = 7
and new_accounttype = 2  
group by new_mprnnumber, 
         new_customernumber
)
SELECT b.*
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN Billing.dbo.bill b ON c.MaxBillDate = b.billingPeriodEndDate AND c.new_mprnnumber = b.MPRN
```